# Android : Connection between Server and Client

Tags: android, sockets, bluetooth, serversocket

I am trying to connect `Bluetooth` server and client .While doing so ,Sometime it get connected and work properly and sometime it shows error because of not get connected to the `Socket`.

I am not able to find out the problem with this. The code is as follow which I have used :-

```
private Runnable reader = new Runnable()
    {

        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            try 
            {
                android.util.Log.e("TrackingFlow Client", " Found: " + remoteDevice.getName());
                UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("4e5d48e0-75df-11e3-981f-0800200c9a66");
                socket = remoteDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
                socket.connect();

                android.util.Log.e("TrackingFlow Client", "Connected...");
                os = new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
                is = socket.getInputStream();

                //new Thread(writter).start();
                android.util.Log.e("TrackingFlow Client", "CONTINUE_READ_WRITE" + CONTINUE_READ_WRITE);
                int bufferSize = 1024;
                int bytesRead = -1;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                //Keep reading the messages while connection is open...
                while(CONTINUE_READ_WRITE)
                {
                    android.util.Log.e("TrackingFlow Client", "Reading Started");
                    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    bytesRead = is.read(buffer);
                    if (bytesRead != -1)
                    {
                        String result = "";
                        while ((bytesRead == bufferSize) && (buffer[bufferSize-1] != 0))
                        {
                            result = result + new String(buffer, 0, bytesRead - 1);
                            bytesRead = is.read(buffer);
                        }
                            result = result + new String(buffer, 0, bytesRead - 1);
                            sb.append(result);
                    }

                    android.util.Log.e("TrackingFlow Client", "Read: " + sb.toString());

                    //Show message on UIThread
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable()
                    {   
                        @Override
                        public void run() 
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, sb.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        }
    };
```

Comment: When it does not work, what information do you get?